# What is a "rolling correction"? What is the usage and meaning of the expression “rolling correction”?

Tags: expressions

What can a "rolling correction" mean, other than the let's say scientific meaning of correcting the rolling trajectory of a certain object.

See, e.g. [CNBC](http://www.cnbc.com/2015/08/12/this-could-be-the-correction-markets-are-waiting-for.html):

> Boockvar said Wednesday's dramatic snap back in the market did not
>   dissuade him from his view. "We've had a rolling correction. We're
>   going to have buyers on the dip, as we did today, but I'm not changing
>   my opinion that going into September, there's a very high chance of a
>   correction," he said. The Dow was down more than 275 points Wednesday
>   morning and ended the day just 40 points lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correction in the stock market is a sell-off by investors, depressing stock prices. A *rolling correction* is a sell-off that proceeds one market sector after another. It's possible that a "corrected" sector may bounce back as the next sector takes its hit. (That's what "buyers on the dip" means in the OP: investors moved in to buy the cheaper stock in the sector that had taken a dip, i.e., a price loss). Here's a [description](http://seekingalpha.com/article/23619-rolling-correction-may-foreshadow-general-correction) from a previous market event:

> So far this has been a rolling correction: First the homebuilders, then the health care sector, next the transports, and most recently energy and materials have gone into the tank.